# Difference between clustering functions in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to understand the difference between the varclus function and the hclustvar function for clustering in R. I understand that in the varclus function you can specify a similarity measure, i.e. spearman, pearson. Can I do something similar using the hclustvar function? What is the similarity measure set as default in the hclustvar function in R?

Comment: This is not a specific programming question and therefore is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you are curious about the statistical methods for clustering, you would be better off asking over at [stats.se] where statistical topics are appropriate.